# Gettting following Error in updated flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

[![Before updating flutter everything was fine and after i updated flutter then i got error while debugging, so i downloaded the flutter again and then got same error. Iam getting following error.Please help me....

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not download flutter_embedding_debug.jar (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c)
  >   Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.jar'.
  >   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 876192; received: 720
  >   Could not download x86_64_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c)
  >   Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-e1e6ced81d029258d449bdec2ba3cddca9c2ca0c.jar'.
  >   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 10307141; received: 716
  >   ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIr8K.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIr8K.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys It was just because I Was using college wifi with firewall and it was preventing to download .jar file. When I switched to another network it worked fine.